# Bounds of a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

Find the bounds of the function $\frac{|\sec x|}{\sqrt{2}} (\sqrt{2-4\cos 2x} + 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2+3\cos2x})$

I first tried putting conditions for the square roots to exist to obtain bounds on $\cos 2x$. Then wrote $\sec {x}$ in terms of $\cos 2x$. But the resulting expression seems very complicated

Answer (score 1):

Consider the positive side because of the symmetry and make $x=\cos ^{-1}(t)$. The expression becomes
$$f(t)=\frac{2 }{t}\left(\sqrt{3-4 t^2}+\sqrt{6 t^2-1}\right)$$ The first derivative
$$f'(t)=\frac{2 }{t^2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6 t^2-1}}-\frac{3}{\sqrt{3-4 t^2}}\right)$$
Let $y=t^2$ and we need to solve for $y$
$$\sqrt{3-4 y}=3\sqrt{6 y-1} \implies y=\frac 6 {29}\implies t_*=\sqrt{\frac 6 {29}}$$ So, the maximum is
$$f(t_*)=4 \sqrt{\frac{14}{3}}$$ and this is the upper bound.

Now, it is your turn.